# MVC 6 reference issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a quite obscure problem with assemblies in mvc6. Just today I installed ASP.NET beta 7 ( from here: beta  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True)  and mvc 6 for my solution (via a nuget command: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Pre ), everything worked fine before I added some references like Microsoft.VisualBasic or System.Drawing. Now I get ,,the type or namespace name could not be found" for all of them. I am pretty confident that I added the referencies to the assemblies. Anyone else encountered this issue ? Tried creating a new project and adding the same references- same problem. Also, intellisense is working fine, it has problems with references only at build-time.

UPD: here is the project.json

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "SpreadsheetGear2012.Core": "1.0.0-*",
        "SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing": "1.0.0-*"
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "Microsoft.VisualBasic": "10.0.0.0",
        "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show your `project.json`.

Comment: @DaveZych I added it to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you are targeting both `dnx451` and `dnxcore50` but only add a dependency to `System.Drawing` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic` in `dnx451`. When you compile, it doesn't know how to resolve the `System.Drawing` and `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespaces when compiling against `dnxcore50`. To resolve it, you can either:

Remove the target to `dnxcore50` in your `project.json`:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "SpreadsheetGear2012.Core": "1.0.0-*",
      "SpreadsheetGear2012.Drawing": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "Microsoft.VisualBasic": "10.0.0.0",
      "System.Drawing": "4.0.0.0"
    }
  }
},
```

or compile with `#if DNX451` wherever you use `System.Drawing` or `Microsoft.VisualBasic`:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
#if DNX451
    var bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap("file");
#endif
}
```